# text file not updating in the run problem c#

Tags: c#, output

I have the following code:

```
strCmdText = "/C cppcheck.exe --enable=all " + StrFile1 + " 2> " + StrfolderOut + "\\fileOut.txt";
//Console.WriteLine(strCmdText);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

but when I'm trying to read it afterwards is like the program executes it after finishing the execution

I ran 2 test:

First one  I use as an input "file1.txt" (fileOut does not exist) the file is created by cmd redirecting the output using ">". When trying to read it it says "the file does not exist"

Secondly, I use "file2.txt" as an input (fileOut does existe and has the info of file2.txt) and it reads but the content of "file1.txt".

So I think that the cmd command runs after finishing the execution. I triple checked the paths so is not a problem since im reading the path using file folder gui.

I'm using this code to read

```
public List<Error> LeerArchivo()
{
    List<Error> listaErrores = new List<Error>();

    string @folderLocation = StrfolderOut + "\\fileOut.txt";
    Console.WriteLine(@folderLocation);
    //OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    //openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
    if (File.Exists(@folderLocation))
    {
        try
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@folderLocation))
            {
                string line = "";
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                Console.WriteLine("reading");
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }           
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("no existe");
    }

    return listaErrores;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage it to work, I used:

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
 {do cppcheck... etc}
 process.Start();
 process.WaitForExit();
```

It works now, I think it is since the main program waits for that process to finish. Maybe I can have a deeper explanation of what happening.